# Simplifying $\tan^{-1}\frac{a\sin{x}+b\cos{x}}{a\cos{x}-b\sin{x}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I get:
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)+x$$
from
$$\tan^{-1}\frac{a\sin{x}+b\cos{x}}{a\cos{x}-b\sin{x}}$$
?
There doesn't seem to be anything left to factor and the only identity use I can think of is the that gives me tangent terms in the equation but that didn't lead me anywhere. Any hint would be appreciated.

(Edit: I was simply stuck on this identity that I encountered in a book on dynamical systems so I figured I'd ask here. Not sure what more details I could provide as it's just a trig problem. I hope it doesn't get deleted since the visual hint provided below and selected as best answer could be helpful to others.)

Comment: WLOG $$a=r\cos t, b=r\sin t$$

Comment: As a follow up on lab's hint, keep in mind that $\sin x \cos y + \sin y \cos x = \sin {(x+y)}$ and $\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y = \cos {(x + y)}$.

Comment: Technically, without further conditions being stated, this identity is not valid. For example, let $a=b=1$ and let $x=\pi.$ Then $\tan^{-1}\frac{a\sin{x}+b\cos{x}}{a\cos{x}-b\sin{x}}=\frac\pi4$ but $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)+x=\frac54\pi.$ This is an extreme example; anything where $\lvert\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)+x\rvert>\frac\pi2$ will do this, and there are many such examples even for $\lvert x\rvert<\frac\pi2.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geometrical proof : can you prove your identity using  the following figure with the indications herein ?

[image]

Comment: $\tan^{-1}\frac{BE+CE}{AB-FC}=\tan^{-1}\frac{FG}{AG}=\tan^{-1}\frac{AF\sin{\theta+x}}{AF\cos{\theta+x}}=\tan^{-1}\tan{\theta+x}=\tan^{-1}\frac{EF}{EA}+x=\tan^{-1}\frac{b}{a}+x$. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

We know
\begin{cases}a\sin x+b\cos x=R\sin(x+\theta)\\a\cos x-b\sin x=R\cos(x+\theta)\end{cases}where $R=\sqrt{a^2+b^2},\theta=\arctan\left(\dfrac ba\right)$

Hence
\begin{align}S&=\arctan\left(\dfrac{a\sin x+b\cos x}{a\cos x-b\sin x}\right)\\&=\arctan\left(\dfrac{R\sin(x+\theta)}{R\cos(x+\theta)}\right)\\&=\arctan(\tan(x+\theta))\\&=x+\theta\\&=x+\arctan\left(\dfrac ba\right)\end{align}

Comment: You need to be careful about simplifying $\arctan\tan(x+\theta)$, or even inferring which $\theta$ satisfy $\cos\theta=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\,\sin\theta=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help.